# jQuery - if element exists then target itself and previous element

Tags: jquery, inline

Like the title says I am trying to see if an element exists and then add inline CSS to itself and the previous  element.

This is a WordPress plugin that is outputting this basic HTML:

```
<p>
 <span class="start-date"> June 25, 2019 </span>
 &nbsp; - &nbsp;
 <span class="end-date"> June 28, 2019 </span>
</p>
```

jQuery that I am trying to use:

```
if ($(".end-date").length){
  $(this).css('display', 'inline');
  $(this).prev().css('display', 'inline');
}
```

I thought this would work but obviously doesn't because I'm here asking for help,  so any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any need to set display as inline for those span tags, since span tags already are inline elements. There will be a need if the plugin or the 'start-date' and 'end-date' classes are changing the display property.

Comment: Well what I didn't add in there is that the span element "start-date" is set to inline-block with a width of 100%. Because "end-date" is not always present in the output and when it is not the span ".start-date" needs to be 100% width and text-align: center. But when it does appear I need both spans to be "inline"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're expecting the condition body to change the `this` context to the matched element. It's not, because it's not a callback.

```
let ed = $(".end-date");
if (ed.length){
  ed.css('display', 'inline');
  ed.prev().css('display', 'inline');
}
```

Comment: That actually really made sense. I am still learning JS and jQuery so this was very helpful. Thank you!